# Brownian Motion covariance function - I can't the see steps in this proof.

Tags: statistics, brownian-motion, covariance

The following is taken from *Selfsimilar Processes* by Paul Embrechts:

[image]

I have only seen this before as: $\ E[B(t)B(s)]$ (without the ' prime next to the $\ B(s)$)

The technique I have seen before involves using the substitution:

$\ B(s) = B(t) + (B(s) - B(t))$

And after some rearranging, you pop out that:

$\ E[B(t)B(s)] = t$ if you arbitrarily picked $\ t<s$ or

$\ E[B(t)B(s)] = s$ if you arbitrarily picked $\ s<t$, (which is the same result as above, albeit less elegant.)

BUT: I can't see (a) what the prime is supposed to denote in Embrechts' proof and (b) how he gets the first line of his proof.

(a) I initially thought the prime was supposed to specify that $\ B(s)'$ is a different Brownian Motion to $\ B(s)$. But then in the first line of the proof, the prime is scoping over an entire bracket: $\ ((B(t) - B(s))'$. Is this meant to be the incremental noise process for the separate 'primed' Brownian Motion? What would be the motivation for distinguishing between 2 separate processes?

(b) The jump is just not clear to me.

Many thanks, all!

EDIT: the $\ I$ in Embrechts' proof is the identity matrix, since this is supposed to hold true of general n-dimensional Brownian motion.

Comment: The prime is for the matrix transpose.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense, thank you Dark. I can see that it wouldn't be well formed to include the Identity Matrix, unless the transpose was included.

Comment: Kind of harsh to give me a down-vote for this. Isn't a superscript T more common? Of course now thanks to Dark I can see that the prime couldn't have meant anything else, and I see the rest of the steps very simply. But what is this site for if not for asking such things? Pedantry.